# Validator error message contains label value

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How can I achieve such thing:

When I define field
`$builder->add('City', 'text', array('required' => false))` and add `Constraint` NotBlank, I want error message to be `Field City canot be empty` so that Label will be part of error message

Answer (score 1):

How can a field either not be required and not be empty?

Anyway, if you want to set a custom message to a Constraint, you can do it using the message options. IE:

PHP:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
new Assert\NotBlank(array(
    'message' => 'Field City can not be empty.'
));
```

YAML:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Foo:
    properties:
        City:
            - NotBlank: {message: Field City can not be empty.}
```

Comment: I want to change default message, to containt label value, and not to set for each field error message